# Problema con OpenCV en Python

Tags: python, cv2

**Post actualizado**

Expongo mi problema, yo recibo por telegram en mi canal, fotos de una camara que tengo en casa, con un detector de movimiento saca fotos y me las envia al canal, necesito tratar o incluirle algún filtro de brillo/contraste a esas imagenes, según la luz del dia utilize un filtro u otro, pasandoselo al cv2 para aplicar al filtro y reenviarla sobre la marcha al canal.

Tras hablar con Abulafia por chat para aclarar unos fallos de uso de la librería de telethon, he aclarado las ideas y el código, ademas de no necesitar pasar a bytes la imagen ya que puedo obtenerla con el await como pongo aquí abajo, teniendo la imagen solo necesito aplicarle el filtro y reenviarla, pero me da ese error, y he probado algunas cosas pero no he logrado solventarlo:

Mi código seria esto:

```
alpha = 2.1
beta = -120
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):        
    foto = await (client.download_media(event.photo))
    #img = cv2.imread(foto)    
    nphoto = (alpha * foto) + beta
    await event.client.send_message(entity, nphoto)
```

Igualmente, me gustaría saber como extraer los bytes, y tras tener el método de telethon aclarado, espero vuestra ayuda!

Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88640/discussion-between-abulafia-and-peisou).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que no tengo acceso a tu *framework* que recibe los mensajes, pero sí a la biblioteca CV2, voy a intentar "simular" tu situación, y espero que la simulación sea lo bastante aproximada a tu caso como para que esto te sirva.

## Indagaciones iniciales

¿En qué formato está la imagen que recibes? Extraigo los bytes de tu código, quedándome con la cadena de bytes que hay en el campo `bytes`:

```
foto = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x0e\n\x0b\r\x0b\t\x0e\r\x0c\r\x10\x0f\x0e\x11\x16$\x17\x16\x14\x14\x16, !\x1a$4.763.22:ASF:=N>22HbINVX]^]8EfmeZlS[]Y\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x0f\x10\x10\x16\x13\x16*\x17\x17*Y;2;YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00<\x00Z\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x02\x03\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\xff\xc4\x008\x10\x00\x01\x03\x02\x03\x05\x05\x05\x06\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x00!\x04\x121\x13AQS\x91\x05\x14"q\x81\x15#Ra\xa123br\x92\xd1\x064BT\x82\xb1\xe1\xff\xc4\x00\x18\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\xff\xc4\x00\x1e\x11\x01\x00\x02\x01\x05\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x11\x03\x02\x12\x13Q\xa11\xb1\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xf6\x98\x97\xde\x18\x97B\\\xca\x94\x91\x12\x05U\xde1\x1f\xdc\xa7\xe9Z\xb1\xad\xe1\x1amx\x9cL\x81\xbc\xe67\xaeN\x0b\xb4\xbb7\x19\x8a,\x86\x9co\x81*\xff\x00\xb5wG\xc7\x9aqd\x99\x99\x8f\xd6\xb71/\xa0\xd9\xf0\xaf );\xee#\x9az\n\xda\xbc\x02\x02\xfc,\xa4\xa2\x05\xd4\xe1\x06o;\xbc\xaa\x1c\x0b|\xa4\xfa8\x7fj\xb7\x0c\xf1e\xef\xd6.\xfb\x88\xe6\x1e\x82\xa7}\xc4sOA[;\x82y(\x89\xe6\xab\xf6\xa8p(\x9b4\x93m\xce\x9dzR\xe18\xb2\xf7\xeb\x1f}\xc4s>\x82\xa7~\xc4sOA]\x04\xf6{\x19|M\xc1\xfc\xe4\xd1\xf6~\x1b\xe1>\x8a4\xb88\xb2\xf7\xeb\x9d\xdfq\x1c\xc3\xd0T\xef\xb8\x8ei>\x82\xba>\xcf\xc3G\xd8?\xa8\xd4\xf6~\x1b\xe1\'\xc9F\x97\x07\x16^\xfds\xbb\xee#\x98z\n\xed\x85Xx\xbe\x95\x97\xd9\xf8o\x80\xfe\xa3Z\x81\xb0\xf1T\x97lZ5i\xbd\xd2\xe1\x7f\x17a\xf1Ov@s\x08\xda\x9e[\x0em\x0bcU\x08 \xc7Z\xf1\x9d\x95\x82\xed\'\x1eK\xad\xb0\xb4\xb8\xfaB\x82.-\x98\t>\x86o\xc2\xbe\x98\xe3\x8aB\x90\x12\xda\xdc\n0H\xd0R\xa4\x94\x15\x14\xb1\x94\x93{\x8b\xd66\xc5\xdb\xbd\xcc|g\xc6a\xf6\xcf}\xf6!$\xb7\x96\x1bt$k\xaf\x9e\x82j\xb5a\xca\x91\x05\xccV\\\xc0\xfd\xeaf\xc2:\x1dkj\x8av\x833Ej\xcb\xac\x03n\x14\xb9\xd1\x9b.\xc4\x8f\xf1\x15\xa4c8E\xc0)\xc4c\x14\x006S\xa9\x99\x91\x1f-\xdfZ|C\x1br\xd8+}\x1b3\x00\xa1\xc0\t\x98\xb9\xe9ZB\x91\x7fp\xa9\xe0R\x05\x1c\xe9\xe4\xa8|\xb2\x8a\x0es\xb8g\x90\x9c\xc8s\x1a\xe2\x8d\xa0\xe2\x12 q\xd3\xe5Jp\xef\xa5nd\x18\xa5%\xc9R\x921\x00\x00Ur\x05\xb7O\xd2\xba\x87(XN\xc1G\x81\xca"\x88X\n!(#\xc9:\xd5\x84\x96\x0c.\r\xe7AS\xee\xe3\x19 \xd8\x17\x81\x9e\x82\xba-\'f\xda\x1b\xce\xa5e\x012nO\x99\xa5\x0e\xca\xa3f\xb1\xc4\xabu!\xc5$\x18\x85zG\xefQa\xa0yu\xa1\xd2\x95\n\xce\t\t#\xf3S\x82 \\P\x01~&\x89\xd7p\xa1\xeaO\x95\x1d\xdaE\x06LL\x17@)\x0b9l!?>&\xaa\xca\x12\xa1)I\x04\\\xe5D\xa6\xfakV\xe2\xb2\xa9\xd4\xa5F\xe4Z\xe9\x13\xe8j\xa3\x96sg\x8e2\xa4\xf5\xd2\x82\xc4\xb2\xd0"V\xda\x80\xfc\t\x16\xa3\xb1nD:\xd8\x83 eM\xb7\xd5R\x95\x10\xa0\xbbN\xe2\x8f\x0f\xd2\x9d2\xec\xa9\xbd,<%\x04\x0byPM\x93rr\xba\xd4N\x99\x13\x03\xe5\xfe\xe9\x94\xcbEC\xde4\x14\x9b}\x84\xebV\x00L\x93\x87\x93\xc6E\xe8\x90D\x9d\x82g]D\xd0R[mh\x1e\xf5\xa5\x14\xd8\x92\x94\xd3\x86P\xa8\xca\xb6\x8a\x81\x99\x08\x04\xd3\x10J\x7f\x97\x9e"E\x10T\x95xXH1\xa8"\x81\x9akf"\x01\x9d\xf9@\xa7\x1a\x7fM\x04\x12\xa4\xca\x92A\xe0M0\xd0i@7k\xd2\x8c|\xa8\x02I\x89\xa3\x11AZ\xd2\x14\xab\xb8\xa0b \x18\xa4\xd9\x82,\xf2\xaf\xbf0\xab\x0bhq^$\xa4\xee\xb8\x146\r$Y\xb4_\xf0\x8a\x05-\x05\x08\x0f8?)\x14\xed\xb6PL\xa9J\x9f\x88\xd4KH\x0b\x94\xa5)"\xc0\x80\x051\x11\xa5\x04\xeah\x8bp\x15"I\xb9\xa0m\xa5\x01\xeaji\xc0P\x89&\xe6\xa1\xb1\xb5\x01\xeah\x01m\x05\x10\'Rh\xe5\x1c(?\xff\xd9'
```

Guardando eso en un fichero, mediante el código:

```
with open("fichero", "wb") as f:
  f.write(foto)
```

la guardo a un archivo (sin extensión) y uso el comando `file`  de Unix, para que me diga qué es:

```
$ file fichero
fichero: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 72x72, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 90x60, frames 3
```

Es un JPEG, por tanto uno de los formatos soportados por `cv2`

## Lectura con `cv2`

Una vez está en disco resultaría trivial leerlo, basta un `cv2.imread("fichero")`, el cual he comprobado que funciona correctamente y retorna un array numpy de dimensiones `(60, 90, 3)` (lo que coincide con la información dada por `file`)

Por desgracia suponemos que la vía "a través de fichero" no nos sirve, y queremos que `cv2` lea directamente los bytes que tengo en la variable `foto`.

Como mencionaba en un comentario, la función para ello es `imdecode()`, pero no era tan fácil de usar como suponía. Para empezar es obligatorio pasarle un segundo parámetro `flags`. Sin él obtienes el error que has visto. En ese parámetro le decimos si queremos leerlo con cualquier profundidad de color, o si queremos pasarlo a blanco y negro, etc.

Pero además el primer parámetro no puede ser el buffer de bytes que tenemos. Espera que sea un vector numpy de bytes. Tras algunos ensayos, doy con la forma correcta:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(foto, dtype=np.byte), flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

La variable `img` resultante es un array numpy como el que se obtenía leyendo el fichero, por tanto tu imagen "decodificada", lista para procesamiento de imágenes o para guardarla en otro fichero.

Veo que tu código la guarda en formato `.png`. Si te valiera también el guardarla en `.jpg`, no necesitarías ese paso intermedio a través de OpenCV, pues *ya te viene en jpeg*. Puedes usar el código que mostré en "indagaciones iniciales" para ver cómo volcarla a disco.

### Actualización

Parece ser que no necesitas volcarla a disco pues sólo quieres procesarla y devolverla. Entiendo que lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
foto = event.original_update.message.photo.bytes

# Decodificar imagen
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(foto, dtype=np.byte), flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Procesarla
newimg= (alpha * img) + beta

# Volver a codificarla como jpg
_, newfoto = cv2.imencode(".jpg", newimg)

# Actualizar el campo bytes de tu foto con newfoto, no sé si así serviría:
event.original_update.message.photo.bytes = newfoto
```

## Edición final

Extraer la foto del mensaje no es tan sencillo como supuse en lo anterior, en donde imaginé que la foto estaría en un campo `bytes`.

Tal campo no existe. Es más, tras mirar la documentación de Telethon y no encontra nada, acabé mirando el código fuente del mismo, para llegar a la conclusión de que un objeto de tipo `Photo` no contiene en realidad la foto, sino tan solo un *thumbnail*, y que la verdadera foto a diferentes tamaños está aún en el servidor de donde hay que descargarla con `client.download_media()`.

Esta función busca la foto de mayor resolución disponible y la descarga, dejándola por defecto en un fichero en el disco, y retornándote una cadena con el nombre del fichero en cuestión.

Ya que queremos evitar el acceso a disco, para que todo sea más rápido, estuve indagando de nuevo en el fuente y encontré que, al menos en la versión 1.5.4 de Telethon, la función `client.download_media()` admite un parámetro `file` y si le das el valor `bytes`, no guarda nada en disco, sino que te devuelve la foto como una cadena de bytes. ¡Justo lo que necesitamos!

Así pues el código que descarga la imagen y la procesa con OpenCV quedaría así:

```
foto = await client.download_media(event.photo, file=bytes)
if foto is not None: 
   img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(foto, dtype=np.byte), flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
   newimg = alpha * img + beta 
   _, newfoto = cv2.imencode(".jpg", newimg)
```

Ahora ya sólo te queda averiguar cómo reenviar al canal la foto procesada.

Comment: eres un crack! +∞ muchisimas gracias